# Can I ignore warnings C4056 and C4756 from ODE after upgrading to VC12?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, ode-library

After upgrading our IDE from Visual Studio 2010 (VC10) to Visual Studio 2013 (VC12), our use of `dInfinity`, a macro defined in Open Dynamics Engine (ODE), started to generate compiler warnings:

> C4056: overflow in floating-point constant arithmetic
>
> C4756: overflow in constant arithmetic

In **odeconfig.h** (ode)

```
#ifdef INFINITY
  #define dInfinity INFINITY
#elif defined(HUGE_VAL)
  #ifdef dSINGLE
    #ifdef HUGE_VALF
      #define dInfinity HUGE_VALF
    #else
      #define dInfinity ((float)HUGE_VAL)
    #endif
  #else
    #define dInfinity HUGE_VAL
  #endif
#else
  #ifdef dSINGLE
    #define dInfinity ((float)(1.0/0.0))
  #else
    #define dInfinity (1.0/0.0)
  #endif
#endif
```

In **math.h** (VC12; *The comments in there are from the header file, I did not add them there.*)

```
#define _HUGE_ENUF  1e+300  /* _HUGE_ENUF*_HUGE_ENUF must overflow */
#define INFINITY   ((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))  /* causes warning
                    C4756: overflow in constant arithmetic (by design) */
```

The previous version was probably using `HUGE_VAL` which did not spam warnings.

`C4756` seems to come from the simple use in a `float` and `C4056` seems a result to an implicit conversion to a `double`.

Can I simply ignore these warnings by wrapping the inclusion of `odeconfig.h` in `#pragma warning push`/`pop`, or is there really something bad going on?

**Edit**:

After looking at an old setup, the previous implementation used `HUGE_VAL` defined in **math.h**.

Comment: If this can help anyone landing here: we modified `odeconfig.h` to disable the use of `math.h`'s `INFINITY`, and we reverted to the use of `HUGE_VAL`.